# how to get sinatra route_path like in grape

Tags: ruby, sinatra, ruby-grape

I want to report stats for my routes. 
To do that, I have to know what they are 
I am using ruby's sinatra
so I have

```
get '/test/:username' do
  .... 
end

after do
    request.path_info
end
```

But I get '/test/test_username123' as an output

Is there a variable (like grape `route.route_path`) that will enable me to get the route?

Edit: Grape's `route.route_path` will output `"/api/:version/test/:username(.:format)"`

Comment: Not familiar with grape.  Can you give a sample input paired with the desired output?

Comment: maybe check out [sinatra advanced routes](https://github.com/rkh/sinatra-advanced-routes#readme)?